# Unable to Run serenity cucumber in sauce labs

Tags: saucelabs, cucumber-serenity

I am trying to run the automated test in sauce labs for first time but I see no execution takes in sauce lab but instead execution takes place in my local machine. Since I am new to this way of running, I am not sure where is the correction to make.

**Runner.java:-**

```
package Global.ExecutionManager;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"},
        features = "Test",
        glue = "foo"
)
public class TestRunner {

}
```

**Feature**

```
Feature: foo boo.

  Scenario: test
    Given Login with valid "foo" credentials
```

**Step definition file:-**

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Step;

public class credentails extends Auth {

    public credentails() throws SQLException {
        open();
    }

    @Step
    @Given("^Login with valid \"([^\"]*)\" credentials$")
    public void login_with_valid_credentials(String userType) throws InterruptedException {
      // line of codes ....
    }
}
```

**Serenity.properties:-**

```
saucelabs.target.platform=Windows 10
saucelabs.driver.version=latest
saucelabs.url=https://f00:boo@ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub
saucelabs.access.key=boo
saucelabs.user.id=foo
saucelabs.test.name=testing
```

**Expected Results:**

Execution should take place in sauce lab.

**Actual Results:**

Execution takes place in local machine.

Answer (score 1):

OK so yes, and also no.

The yes is that a configuration like this will let you run tests; You *still* have to specify that you're using a remote Webdriver:

```
environment = run_with_saucelabs

environments {
  run_with_saucelabs {
    webdriver.driver = remote
    webdriver.remote.url = "https://un:ac@ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com/wd/hub"
    webdriver.browserName = Firefox
    webdriver.browserVersion = 87
    
    # Some W3C Capabilities
    screenResolution = "1280x1024"
    strictFileInteractability = true
    unhandledPromptBehavior = "ignore"
    timeouts {
      script = 20000
      pageLoad = 400000
      implicit = 1000
    }

    # SauceLabs-specific capabilities
    saucelabs {
      accessKey=un
      userName=ac
      datacenter = "eu-central-1"
    }
  }
}
```

The *no* is that as of writing this response, Serenity is still establishing Selenium sessions with the `version` capability, one of the older JWP capabilities.  That will prevent sessions from actually starting on Sauce Labs (as mixing W3C capabilities with JWP is invalid).

Thankfully, 5 days ago a commit was made to the Serenity project to move to Selenium 4.3.0, which provides the `browserVersion` capability by default; That should make everything run smoothly.  It looks like that'll be available in Serenity 3.2.6.